# SelectedIndex property of listbox always return -1 value

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a listbox with name lbx_Marked, having autopostback turned on and selectedIndexChanged Method. But no matter whatever I do the SelectedIndex value always gets **STICK** To -1.

How to obtain the real SelectedIndex Value?

Below is the code for selectedIndex Method.

```
protected void lbx_Marked_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a;
        int b;
        b=lbx_Marked.SelectedIndex;
        if (lbx_Marked.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            a = " No Selection Made";
        }
    }
```

The code for populating the listBox is as below.

```
private void FillControls()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {   
            int i;
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id,Empname,Designation from TblMstEmp", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "entry");
            for(i=0;i<ds.Tables["entry"].Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                mylist.Add(string.Concat( Convert.ToString( ds.Tables["entry"].Rows[i]["Empname"]),"-",Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["entry"].Rows[i]["Designation"]))) ;
            }

            lbx_Marked.DataSource =mylist;
            lbx_Marked.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WebForms. I just created a new C# WebForms project and added the following ListBox control and Code Behind

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbx_Marked" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbx_Marked_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lbx_Marked.Items.Add(new ListItem("Option 1", "1"));
            lbx_Marked.Items.Add(new ListItem("Option 2", "2"));
            lbx_Marked.Items.Add(new ListItem("Option 3", "3"));
        }
    }

    protected void lbx_Marked_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a;
        int b;
        b = lbx_Marked.SelectedIndex;
        if (lbx_Marked.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            a = " No Selection Made";
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking a different option in the ListBox resulted in a POST back and the SelectIndex always reflected the value of the ListItem

**UPDATED**
I added data in the same manner as you indicated and it still works for me.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            mylist.Add("Option 1");
            mylist.Add("Option 2");
            mylist.Add("Option 3");
            lbx_Marked.DataSource = mylist;
            lbx_Marked.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, its working fine,  but in my case it's not. The only difference is the way the listbox is populated. In case you need them I have updated my question with the code to populate the listbox.

Comment: If you create a brand new page and add a ListBox control and the code behind from the first part of my answer. What bahavior do you experience?

Comment: when i create a new page and add a new listbox then everything works fine,   but i want to figure out what's going wrong in the code that i have written, and there is no point in creating a new page though.

Comment: All we have to work with is what you have divulged. I demo'ed populating a ListBox and successfully running your event handler. You then said  data population is different, so I demo'ed working similar data access. So progress has been made by eliminating some things. With limited info, 2 approaches come to mind. Keep adding the other functionality from your page that does not work to the new page, or remove functionality from the page that does not work until it is slimmed down enough to be similar to the new page. We haven't seen where you populate the ListBox or your HTML source yet

Comment: ok fine, now how to fetch the value of "b" into another method.